# Is it possible to change FBSDK's graph API version?

Tags: android, react-native, fbsdk, react-native-fbsdk

I installed FBSDK for react native a few days ago, and now it seems that using the newest v2.9 the app won't be able to utilize shares as it used to so far. 
Though, we'd still like to come out with a beta version ASAP, and time is of the essence. 
Is it possible to make all graph requests v2.8 for now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FacebookSDK 4.23 has this Graph

```
- (instancetype)
initWithGraphPath:  (NSString *)graphPath
parameters: (NSDictionary *)parameters
tokenString:    (NSString *)tokenString
version:    (NSString *)version
HTTPMethod: (NSString *)HTTPMethod
NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBSDKGraphRequest/